# Apple80211Scan in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1, wifi

I am trying to get the list of available Wireless Networks available and their signal strength. I am trying to use Apple80211Scan Private APIs and using an iOS 7 device (not jail-breaken). So far successful in getting currently connected network's information using Apple80211GetInfoCopy. However the scan API doesn't work. The return code by this method is 1.

I looked at the error codes for the 80211 Scan APIs listed @ http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Scan. However 0 and -1 is alone discussed. Has any one tried this on iOS7. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same issue. I've tried using the core foundation data types instead of the foundation objects even though they are toll free bridged, but still no luck. It seems that NSArray or CFArray is not being allocated when Apple80211Scan is called. Perhaps apple has changed the parameters?

Comment: Never mind, Apple80211Scan's parameters are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple80211Scan will not work on a non jailbroken device due to sandboxing. The return value of 1 signifies that it was unable to scan the network, and the reason why is because Apple simply does not allow you to do this in a sandboxed environment. The only you can use Apple80211Scan is by jailbreaking and installing your app in /Applications on the device to remove the sandboxing.

Comment: Thanks Nico, I was just wondering why the Apple80211GetInfoCopy works without root access while scan doesn't work.